# How to apply pivot_longer to a list of data frames in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, lapply

I currently have a list of 100 imputed data frames:

```
imp <- panImpute(Data, formula = formula, n.burn = 5000, n.iter = 100, m = 100)

# list of 100 imputed datasets
implist <- mitmlComplete(imp, "all")
```

I would like to apply the pivot_longer function from dplyr to each of these data frames in the list.

I've attempted to use the lapply function, but it's not working:

```
lapply(names(implist), function(x) pivot_longer(cols=c("C1_PTAH_log","Post_PTAH_log"),names_to = "time_log",values_to = "values_log"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `lapply` function has the variable `x` for the current data.frame, but you arne't passing `x` to `pivot_longer`. You should pass that in as the first parameter.

Comment: Please add some data, including a formula, that works. Thanks.

Comment: What would I put instead of x?

Comment: @MrFlick is suggesting that you replace `pivot_longer(cols=...` with `x %>% pivot_longer(cols=...` or `pivot_longer(x, cols=...`.  But I think you will need also to replace `names(implist)` with `implist` because you want the function to operate on the elements of `implist` themselves, not the names of the elements of `implist`.  And the elements of the vector `cols` should not be quoted strings.